# Paginate tag pair inserted using Solspace Tag

Tags: solspace, pagination

I'm setting up a new site using Solspace Tag. Everything displays the way I want it to, except that inexplicably a random code pair — {paginate}{/paginate} — is getting inserted.[image: Here's a screen shot of the results I'm getting.]

I've gone through the code for the template and can find no reason for this to happen. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

L.

Edited

Here's the code for the template:

```
{!--- stories/More Stories
    Displays stories that are related to the story because of tags.
    *See template main/index for more template details; only details on this specific template will be documented --}

<div class="page-header"><h3>More stories like this one</h3></div>

    <div class="card-bg">
    <ul id="recent-posts" class="media-list">

    {!-- Displays stories with similar tags --}
    {exp:tag:related_entries limit="5" orderby="relevance" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields|pagination" dynamic="no" paginate="both" status="open|featured"}

        <li class="media card">

          {if news_image}
              <a href="{post_path}" class="pull-left">
              {news_image}
                      <img src={path}/_rect/{filename}.{extension} alt=”{title}” class="img-responsive"/>
              {/news_image}
              </a>
          {if:else}
              <a href="{post_path}" class="pull-left">
              <img src="{site_url}images/posts/rji-post.jpg" alt="{title}" class="img-responsive"/></a>
          {/if}

          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading"><a class="media-heading" href="{post_path}">{title}</a>
              {!-- If statement below checks if there is a start time (it is an event) and gives the event start/finish but if not (it is a post) and displays author and publish date --}
              <br /><span class="small capitalize">
              {entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"} | Relevance: {tag_relevance_percent}%
              </span></h4>
            <span>{teaser}
              {event_teaser}</span> {!-- Only appears if it is from Event channel --}
          </div> {!-- ends .media-body --}

        </li>

    {/exp:tag:related_entries}

    </ul>

</div>
```

I don't want to use pagination with this, as there will ever only be at most 5 entries displayed. I'm trying to get rid of the {paginate}{/paginate} tags that are displaying.

ExpressionEngine 2.10.1
Solspace Tag 4.2.9
PHP 5.3.29
Apache 2.2.22

Comment: Can you post the actual template code in the above post? We can't guess otherwise what tag you're using. Also, what exact version numbers of EE and Tag are you using? If you're looking to use pagination, if you're using `{exp:tag:entries}` for example, try using the pagination code found here: https://solspace.com/docs/tag/entries/#tag_paginate

Comment: Added code and version numbers to the original post.

Comment: Apparently, removing pagination from the disable parameter in exp:tag:related_stories worked, and it appears to display correctly now.